# How does division by np.timedelta64 work?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a piece of code doing those calculations :

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = pd.Timestamp(2022, 1, 1)
b = pd.Timestamp(2022, 7, 1)

x = (b - a) / np.timedelta64(1, "M")  # duration in months
y = (b - a) / np.timedelta64(1, "Y")  # duration in years
```

`x` and `y` values are `5.9467...` and `0.4955...`, which is correct (almost 6 months and a half year).

Can someone know by which float number the division is done ?

For example, for months, it could be dividing by `365/12`, but it is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is:

```
# month
Timedelta('30 days 10:29:06')
```

and:

```
# year
Timedelta('365 days 05:49:12')
```

Which corresponds to the real duration of a [Year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year) (365.2425 days).

You can cheat for the conversion using:

```
a+np.timedelta64(1, "M")-a
```

and:

```
a+np.timedelta64(1, "Y")-a
```

ratio: `12`

```
m = a+np.timedelta64(1, "M")-a
y = a+np.timedelta64(1, "Y")-a
y/m # 12
```